# Setup every time Cosmos-DB emulator on Mac on system restart

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I followed this video for running new Cosmos DB emulator in Mac OS:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUfK6n8UXi8

Steps followed:

1. Visit the Docker Hub and install Docker Desktop for macOS
2. Retrieve the IP address of your local machine. This step is required when Direct mode setting is configured using Cosmos DB SDKs (.NET, Java).

```
ipaddr="`ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1`"
```

3. Pull the Docker image from the registry.

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

4. Run the Docker image with the following configurations:

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 8900:8900 -p 8901:8901 -p 8902:8902 -p 10250:10250 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 -p 10255:10255 -p 10350:10350 -m 4g --cpus=2.0 --name=test-linux-emulator -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=3 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=TRUE -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=$ipaddr -it mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

5. After the emulator is running, using a different terminal, load the IP address of your local machine into a variable.

```
ipaddr="`ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1`"
```

6. Next, download the certificate for the emulator.

```
curl -k https://$ipaddr:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem > emulatorcert.crt
```

7. Open *KeyChain Access* application. Click "File" -> "Import Items" -> "emulatorcert.crt" i.e. the recently downloaded certificate from previous command -> Click "Open".
8. "localhost" certificate will be loaded. Click on the certificate, a pop-up window will open. Select "Always Trust" against "When using this certificate" and close the pop-up window.
9. Open htpps://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html, this should open the emulator.

Earlier, for me, step number 9, the localhost:8081 keeps on loading with no response or error. I followed the above steps again and this time it worked for me.

Currently the issue I am facing is that every time I restart my laptop I have to follow all the above steps again like downloading the latest image and setting up the certificate. While running the docker image I kept the "***AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE***" flag as true, so I expected the state to be preserved.
Is there some mistake in the steps followed because setting up every time is a difficult process.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please share your answer so future readers and I will know how you solved your problem. ✌

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT I followed the same steps again. Probably there was some admin issue that is why it wasn't loading for me. Now the above steps works well.

Comment: We have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I get same experience on windows wsl2 with ubuntu. The db handles container restarts from docker desktop ui but not after a win shutdown.  Stopping the container from UI, reboot, then start container and it starts fine.  Seems the emulator container isn't shutdown cleanly during a reboot if it's currently running.  NOTE: the docker container log in UI shows "Started" when all good, else just shows the last but one "Started x/y partitions" message with no final "Started".  I'm thinking that the container isn't given the time it needs to shutdown cleanly.